# Can a US state put a sales tax on foreign made goods?

Tags: united-states, federalism, taxes

e.g. NAFTA is currently in place so there is no Federal tariff on many goods from Mexico. Can Texas put a state sales tax on the sale of goods manufactured in Mexico?

Answer (score 6):

No.

The U.S. Constitution empowers Congress to regulate foreign and interstate commerce, and the Supreme Court has consistently interpreted this to mean that the individual states *cannot* regulate such commerce. This legal interpetation is known as the [dormant commerce clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dormant_Commerce_Clause).

A *state* tax that applies to in-state commerce differently than to (all or some of) comparable out-of-state commerce would be declared unconstitutional as soon as someone sued in federal court to get out of paying it.